# Textboxes not binding correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a bunch of `textboxes` I'm trying to bind to strings in my viewmodel. I thought I had everything set up correctly, but nothing is appearing in the textboxes.

Here's my XAML and one of the textboxes I'm trying to bind.

```
<Window x:Class="Server.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:Server"
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Server.ViewModels"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <TextBlock Name="ShipLatTB"
          FontSize="17"
          Text="{Binding Path=CurrentShipLat, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Here's the viewmodel:

```
namespace Server.ViewModels
{
    class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string _currentShipLat;
        public string CurrentShipLat
        {
            get { return _currentShipLat; }
            set { _currentShipLat = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentShipLat"); }
        }

        // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
}
```

I tested to make sure data is actually in '_currentShipLat' by setting it equal to "test" in a command, and debugged to verify it. Not sure what else is wrong?

Note: This textbox is supposed to be able to dynamically update.

Edit: How about giving a reason for the downvote and voting to close? That doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Did you set the field _currentShipLat after the WPF window is initialized? That way WPF would never 'see' this change because it doesn't trigger the property changed event.
Either make sure the field is set before the window is initialized or use the setter of the property instead of directly setting the field.

Comment: Can you post the xaml where your TextBlock is positioned? I loaded your solution, and for me the values was populated correctly.

Comment: @NathanSwannet You were correct! I was setting it after it was initialized, so I had to use the setter property. Everything works now. If you want to put this as an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: Glad to be of help @pfinferno
I posted it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set the field _currentShipLat before the WPF window is initialized.

If you do it after initialisation of the window, WPF will never 'see' this change because it doesn't trigger the property changed event. Either make sure the field is set before the window is initialized or use the setter of the property instead of directly setting the field.